# How to perform checks before cmake's configuration script is executed?

Tags: configuration, cmake, environment-variables

I get stucked right now with some issues concerning cmake. As it is already a known issue (see [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_MinGW_Compiler_Issues)), calling the MinGW Makefile generator will fail if there is a sh.exe somewhere within the %PATH% environment. This is often the case if people does have a parallel cygwin or msys installation. However, I'd like to create a workaround which searches the %PATH% for an executable called sh.exe and if such path exists, it should be removed from the environment variable. Sure, I can do this with a little precompiled c-program and a batch script (**current solution**) but this requires the user to perform the script before calling cmake which is a little unhandy.
I expected to do something like this within the root CMakeLists.txt

```
if (MINGW)
    "scan for sh.exe and remove eventually"
endif (MINGW)
```

But cmake reads the CMakeLists.txt first after doing its pre-build configurations, which in this case would fail since the path environment hasn't been modified to allow MinGW installation. Is there any way to perform such checks and to change the %PATH% before the configuration of cmake is performed?

And yes, I could do also write another batch script which changes the environment and then calls cmake but this would be rather the final option I would consider for my purposes :).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with a CMake Toolchain file (normally used for cross compiling). The toolchain file is executed before the compiler tests.

Read more about the [toolchain file](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file). The file itself is a normal CMake file, so your pseudocode in the question should work fine.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=fixmingw.cmake
```

The obvious downside is of course that you still need the user to run a different command from the 'normal' CMake command, I don't think there is a way around that.